# How to set permission for action

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there any way to set permission to an action in controller based on group of user? I was trying to set it via authorization plugin, but it doesn't work as I would. Auth plugin set permission on entities or tables, is it right?

Comment: CakePHP version? for 4.x read https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authorization.html#creating-our-first-policy and https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/policies.html